# How do you solve django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I get the following error when I do `python manage.py makemigrations`:

```
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration leads.0001_initial dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('auth', '0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length')
```

This is a part of my 0001_initial.py:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        ('auth', '0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='User',
            ...
```

How am I supposed to solve this error? Currently, I am in production. Thank you, and please leave a comment if you have any questions.

Comment: Did you remove any migrations? It seems that you removed the `0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length` migration.

Comment: No, I don't think so. I don't know if this would help, but I just uploaded my new django app through filezilla, and I installed all of my pip. Then, I did makemigrations, but this error showed up. Also, I have already reseted my database in the server.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem The django app worked fine during development, and I had no errors when I did makemigrations. However, I am suddenly getting this error after I uploaded the app online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with the Django version:

Because this migration file `0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length` must be in this directory: `/lib/python3.*/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/migrations/` but it doesn't exist now and you will receive an error.

In your case I think you are using the oldest version of Django(`< 3.1.0`) and this migration file does not exist, to solve this problem you can upgrade Django version to `>= 3.1.0`.